# get specific div content from responseText and save source code into a database

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to get a specific div content including all the elements of another page from responseText

the body of the html file looks like this:

```
<div id="div_1">
    <div><h1> Title 1 </h1></div>
    <div><img src="blah1.jpg" /></div>
    <div><p> Lorem Ipsum </p></div>
</div>
<div id="div_2">
    <div><h1> Title 2 </h1></div>
    <div><img src="blah2.jpg" /></div>
    <div><p> Lorem Ipsum </p></div>
</div>
```

here is my function to get the source code of the entire html page:

```
function getSourceCode() {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            var source_code = xmlhttp.responseText;
            alert(source_code);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","test.html",true);
    xmlhttp.send(); 
}
```

my question now is how to get only the source code for the "div_1" element. I want to save this source code into a database. I tried to use getElementbyId("div_1") but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to `.filter()` out the required element and get its innerHtml by using `.html()`,

```
$(source_code).filter('#div_1').html()
```

Comment: Thanks! It works fine now! Is it possible to change the the src of the image?

Comment: @user3656648 Glad to help..! and if you think that this answer has satisfied your requirement, then try to click in that tick mark available on the left top corner of this answer.. Thanks.. And that's not a compulsion... :)

Comment: Already done. There was timer therefor I had to wait. But I do have another question. Is it possible to change the src of the img? the html file is just a copy of an external page. because of that the image is on the external server. I need to add  the external server to the src. is that possible?

Comment: @user3656648 sure we can do that.. just ask that one as a new question, so that you could get more attention over that.. and link me to that question if you wish.. :)

Comment: here is my new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23763183/xmlhttprequest-responsetext-get-the-full-source-code

Comment: not working for me. var source_code = ajax.responseText;
                var jar = $(source_code).filter('#sentencias').html();