# XMLHttpRequest responseText get the full source code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to get the the full source code of a page e.g. www.google.com

I got a PHP file to copy the source code of a page:

```
<?php
    echo file_get_contents('http://www.google.com');
?>
```

My function to get the source code:

```
function sendRequest() {
 var xmlhttp;
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
     xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
 else {// code for IE6, IE5
     xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }

 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
         var source_code = xmlhttp.responseText;
         alert(source_code);
         var element = $(source_code).filter("#specificelement").html();
     }
    }
xmlhttp.open("GET","test2.php",true);
xmlhttp.send(); 
}
```

1)Why doesn't it show the full source code? Is there a limit or am I doing something wrong?
I want to get a specific element within the source code.

2) If I'm able to get the specific element, is there a way to add something to the src path? The actual images are on the external server of the original page. Therefore I need to add the server before the actual image.

now: `<img src="/images/blah.jpg" />`

what I want: `<img src="http://server.com/images/blah.jpg" />`

**UPDATE:**

If I do this the full source code is shown in the text area.

`document.getElementById("textarea").innerHTML = source_code;`

Is there a way to get only the code of a specific element from here?

Comment: What makes you think it isn't showing you the full source code?

Comment: On the source site (especially with google), there might be quite a lot of JS, which generates content. As long as you do not run that JS (or can't, e.g., because of some Same Origin Policy issues), your code would fail.

Comment: Most sites out there will use relative URLs for their content. What you need to do is use a regex to find links starting with / and prepending them with the root domain you're running your code for (in this case server.com)

Answer (score 0):

When you are getting the code through file_get_contents, the AJAX Request interprate that code, because it's its functionality, AJAX interprate the response.

Good luck.